# Calculating correlation for angles (and other kinds of circular data)

Tags: correlation, circular-statistics

I have two sequences of angles in radians. I can compute the Pearson correlation coefficient between them. It turns out to be very low since the angles are sort of bimodal distributions with the two centers at 0 and pi. I can see that the problem is that the cyclic nature of angles is not taken into account.

What are the alternatives to Pearson correlation coefficient for angles?

Answer (score 4):

I think the key here is to utilize the Sine function. One option is to simply calculate the correlation of the Sine of the angles. Another is to calculate the Circular Correlation Coefficient (cor.circular function from the circular library in R). This statistic is designed as a measure of correlation between two angular variables and relies on the Sine function as well. I ran some quick simulations which indicate that these two methods give extremely similar results, which is no surprise when you look at the equation for circular correlation. Both of these methods give much better results than the Pearson correlation coefficient.